# Openssh client is blocking forever if stderr is redirected to stdout

Tags: ssh, stdout, stderr

It seems there might be a problem in the `openssh`. In the `bash` shell if I redirect `stderr` to `stdout` it's blocking forever, so I have to `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
$ ssh -fTNF './config' -MS './sockd5/ctrl_socket' -i './keys/id_rsa' -l 'root' -p '22' 'example.com' 2>&1 | cat -A; echo OK
ControlSocket ./sockd5/ctrl_socket already exists, disabling multiplexing^M$
^C
```

Same command without the redirection works just fine:

```
$ ssh -fTNF './config' -MS './sockd/ctrl_socket' -i './keys/id_rsa' -l 'root' -p '22' 'example.com' | cat -A; echo OK
ControlSocket ./sockd/ctrl_socket already exists, disabling multiplexing
OK
```

Why is this happening? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

When `ssh -f` is "going into the background" after having connected and authenticated to the host, it will continue to hold open handles to its original stdin, stdout and stderr, so if those handles were connected via pipes to other processes (as its stdout + stderr are in your example to the `cat -A`), it will have the effect of keeping those processes alive, even if they're no longer needed.

`ssh` daemonizes itself by calling the [`daemon(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) library function, but it calls it with `noclose = 1`, preventing it from redirecting the stdin/stderr/stdout from `/dev/null`.

This was partially fixed in recent versions of `openssh` (for the master control process -- the stdin and stdout in [2010](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/00d9ae26db2a8176f8ff511c207fa0bc7fadd562), the stderr in [2016](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/d2d6bf864e52af8491a60dd507f85b74361f5da3); for the session process -- the stdout in [2017](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/4d5456c7de108e17603a0920c4d15bca87244921)), but if you have to run an older ssh, or need it to stop clinging to stderr too, the only "solution" may be to use a `LD_PRELOAD` hack which overrides the `daemon(3)` function with a wrapper which calls the original with `noclose = 0`.

```
$ cat daemon-force-close.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <err.h>

int daemon(int nochdir, int noclose){
        static int (*orig)(int, int);
        if(!orig && !(*(void**)&orig = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "daemon")))
                errx(1, "%s", dlerror());
        return orig(nochdir, 0);
}

$ cc -shared -Wall -O2 daemon-force-close.c -ldl -o daemon-force-close.so

$ LD_PRELOAD=./daemon-force-close.so \
   ssh -Nf dummy@localhost -MS ./ctlsock 2>&1 | cat -A
dummy@localhost's password:
$
[no Ctrl-C needed]
$ ssh -S ~/w/c/ctlsock dummy@localhost
Last login: Tue May 28 21:04:26 2019 from ::1
...
```

Comment: Weird, I'm testing on `Arch Linux` and the `ssh` client version wich is currently installed `OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019`, so I don't quite get it how the fixes from 2010 and 2016 haven't been applied...

Comment: @NarūnasK I've updated the answer with more info; it turns out that the fixes are only partial (only the master control process will let both the stdout and stderr go; the session process will only release the stdout). This explains your observation, and the difference in behavior from the ssh from debian stretch.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this happening?

It's `cat` that needs to be terminated before the shell gets to `echo`. It's "blocking forever" because the `cat` lives.

> Is there a workaround?

In Bash I would use process substitution to run `cat` that doesn't block. With `cat` out of the way it's then easy to `echo OK` only if it's really OK (with `&&` or `$?`). Example:

```
ssh -f … > >(cat -A) 2>&1 && echo OK; echo "The script goes on."
```

Now `cat` works before and after `ssh` goes to background, but the script continues as soon as `ssh` does it (or as soon as `ssh` fails without going to background).

Comment: Why does `cat` not catch the fact that the other process went into the background? Shouldn't `ssh` close its `stdout` and `stderr` before going into the background? IMHO `ssh` leaves its `stderr` hanging around and therefore `cat` keeps waiting for more input. In other words, technically `cat` is blocking, but the real culprit is `ssh`, right?

Comment: @NarūnasK `ssh` forks and the new instance inherits `stdout` and `stderr`, so the pipe connecting anything to `cat` is open and `cat` sees no difference. The same would be with a named pipe: `cat` reading from a named pipe will exit after *all* processes that write to the pipe close their descriptors. With a named pipe it's easy to experiment on. This is normal, `ssh` is by no means special, so I wouldn't say it's the culprit.

Comment: @NarūnasK Test this with a named pipe: `mkfifo fifo; <fifo cat`. In another console: `exec 7>fifo`. Then `echo foo >fifo`, `echo bar >fifo`, `echo baz >&7`. As long as the shell keeps the descriptor open, many processes can write to the fifo and `cat` works. Finally close the descriptor: `exec 7>&-` and `cat` will exit immediately (unless the fifo is opened for writing by yet another process).

Comment: I'm still confused... What instance inherits `stdout` and `stderr`? To my best understanding `ssh` goes into the daemon mode, so its `stdout`/`stderr` doesn't make sense anymore, thus if it would want to give a feedback to the user it should do that via logs? Note that `ssh -f .... | cat -A; echo OK` works as expected. So if `stdout` and `stderr` get the same treatment from the `ssh`, then the `cat` should still block, waiting for more `stdout`. But it's not the case, `cat` only blocks when `stderr` is redirected, which suggests that `ssh` closes the `stdout`, but leaves `stderr` open.

Comment: Instead of using a process substitution you could just run the whole pipeline in the background (`ssh ... | cat -A & echo YUP`), which would also have to advantage that the shell could notify you when the `cat` kicks the bucket.

Comment: @mosvy I think the point of `ssh -f` is it goes to the backgroud *after* successfully doing few things like asking for password and actually establishing the connection. Just running the whole pipeline in the background will make the rest of the script run prematurely. I imagine it would try to use this master connection (`-M`), so it's good to hold the execution until the connection is really there; and be able to detect failure thanks to `$?`. While doing things your way, you can't even `wait` until the connection is established because `wait` will exit when it's terminated. Not useful.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski right, sorry, I haven't read that carefully. But I'm still not able to grasp the OP's expectations from that. How could ssh close the stderr and print messages to stderr at the same time?

Comment: @NarūnasK The original `ssh` forks, so there is a new one in background. This new instance inherits `stdout` and `stderr` and the old one exits. In my tests I confirmed the new process still pipes to `cat` (I did this by comparing `ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd` for `cat` and `ssh`). In my Debian your original command "blocks" regardless of whether there is `2>&1` or not.

Comment: @mosvy That's the whole point of sending it to the background, that I don't want it to write anything to the `stderr` nor `stdout`. I would just start it in the daemon mode and close the terminal. Job done.

Comment: @NarūnasK If you don't want it to write anything, you should redirect to `/dev/null`, not pipe to `cat`. I thought `cat` is there for a reason (`-A` might be the reason).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski they [fixed it some time ago](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/00d9ae26db2a8176f8ff511c207fa0bc7fadd562) so it no loger clings to stdin and stdout, but the change which makes it let stderr go too is [more recent](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/d2d6bf864e52af8491a60dd507f85b74361f5da3) and didn't made it yet in all the distros.

Comment: @mosvy So at the time being that behaviour with the `stderr` may be considered a bug in the `ssh` client?

Comment: @NarūnasK it's up to you to consider a bug or a feature, but it shouldn't happen in recent versions anymore ;-)